# Version or Found in build dropdown

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Team Service online and I want to automatically add a build/version to a list when a build or release is succeeded. This list I want to use as field in a work item. The already available field "found in build" is only filled in tfs on premise, I found in the manual. I want to add a custom step in the build or release task to add this version to the list. Is this possible?

I have searched the internet and I can only find tips for the on-permise edition.

Other options or tips are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a custom extension that can list all build and fill in the found in field. 
The extension can be found on: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.vsts-rest-multivalue-control

Also it is possible to create a custom private extension.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/custom-control